# Do all lasers excite molecules are only certain types?

Tags: laser

If i want to obtain the most precise information on the inner structure of atoms and molecules i heard the best method is using lasers to excite them. But will any high power laser do? If i have a 40W laser will it even excite the molecules or do scientist use a specifics type?

Comment: I believe only lasers of a specific wavelength excite specific kinds of molecules.

Comment: 40 W is for when you want to vaporize your sample.

Comment: @TheDoctor That sounds like it should be an answer

Comment: Yeah that’s a lot of power if continuous.

Comment: Doctor do you know the exact wave length?

Comment: Try using blue light.

Comment: Is it just blue light? Should i run it at a certain power level as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To study the atomic structure one is in the quantum mechanical area and one has to use photons . [These photons](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod5.html) should have as energy the energy difference between [energy levels in in atom](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hyde.html) .

Lasers are a macroscopic manifestation of quantum states with a specific energy of the photons, h*nu, which will have a width but it cannot be utilized for all atoms, only for the ones that have energy levels with that energy difference. Many different lasers should be used depending on the atoms under study.

A laser with enough energy will melt a solid, but can only give information for energy level differences    of h*nu ( with a small width).